# How to use third party libraries with react functional components?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-functional-component

I have a third party library (Tabulator) that I would like to use with a functional react component.

My current workflow is:

1. Render a placeholder `<div id="tabulator-placeholder"></div>`.
2. Inside `useEffect`: create a Tabulator instance referencing the already existing placeholder.
3. Render a Toolbar that is able to access the Tabulator instance. The toolbar contains an "Apply" button. That button is disabled by default. It's `disabled` attribute is bound to a state variable:  `disabled={!dataIsStale}`.
4. If the data of the Tabulator instance changes, I would like to **update the state variable** and enable the Apply button.

The table and the toolbar are shown as expected.

[image]

If I change the data, my change handler is called.

**However, the change handler does not update the state variable and my Apply button is not enabled.**

=> How should I change the example below to make it work?

I already tried to apply [useRef](https://file-translate.com/en/blog/react-state-in-event) for the `dataIsStale` variable but without success.

(There is also react-tabulator. However, it has some [issues](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues/238). That's why I would like to use Tabulator directly.)

```
import React from 'react';

import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables';
import 'tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator_modern.min.css';


export default function Table(properties) {

    const [toolbar, setToolbar] = React.useState();
    const [dataIsStale, setDataIsStale] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const tabulatorOptions = {         
          columns: [{title: 'name', field: 'name', editor: true}],         
          data: [
              {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
              {id:2, name: 'baa'}
          ]          
        };
        const tabulator = new Tabulator('#tabulator-placeholder', tabulatorOptions);

        let toolbarInstance = <button 
                                  disabled={!dataIsStale}
                                  onClick={()=> alert(JSON.stringify(tabulator.getData()))}
                              >
                               Apply
                              </button>;
        setToolbar(toolbarInstance);

        tabulator.on('dataChanged', displayData => {           
           setDataIsStale(true);
           console.log('Data changed. dataIsStale:' + dataIsStale);
        });       
    },[]);

    return <div>
      {toolbar}
      <div id="tabulator-placeholder"></div>
    </div>;

}
```

Related:

[TypeError: _tabulatorTables.Tabulator is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057036/typeerror-tabulatortables-tabulator-is-not-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I used a state variable for the Tabulator instance instead of using it for the toolbar and now it works.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables';
import 'tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator_modern.min.css';


export default function Table(properties) {

    const [tabulator, setTabulator] = React.useState();   
    const [dataIsStale, setDataIsStale] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const tabulatorOptions = {         
          columns: [{title: 'name', field: 'name', editor: true}],         
          data: [
              {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
              {id:2, name: 'baa'}
          ]          
        };
        const tabulatorInstance = new Tabulator('#tabulator-placeholder', tabulatorOptions);
        tabulatorInstance.on('dataChanged', displayData => {         
           setDataIsStale(true);
           console.log('Data changed. dataIsStale:' + dataIsStale);          
        });  
        setTabulator(tabulatorInstance);        

    },[]);

    let toolbar = <button
        disabled={!dataIsStale}
        onClick={()=> alert(JSON.stringify(tabulator.getData()))}
    >
     Apply
    </button>;

    return <div>
      {toolbar}
      <div id="tabulator-placeholder"></div>
    </div>;

}
```

*Edit*

After a lot of trial and error, I got the custom footer working, too.

The trick was to put the corresponding root object in a state variable and update the root with a second `useEffect`. Without the second `useEffect`, the footer component would not be be updated on property changes.

The relevant parts are:

```
const footer = createFooter(myProperty, ...);
const [footerRoot, setFooterRoot] = React.useState(false);

//... create root inside first useEffect => tableBuilt event of tabulator:

tabulator.on('tableBuilt', () => {
        const footerPlaceHolder = document.querySelector('#footer-element-placeholder');
        const footerRoot = createRoot(footerPlaceHolder);
        setFooterRoot(footerRoot);
      });

// Use a second useEffect to trigger re-render if referenced properties change

React.useEffect(() => {
    if(footerRoot){
      footerRoot.render(footer);
    }
  }, [footerRoot, myProperty]);
```